# BigDecimal 0.000 to 0

Tags: hibernate, plsql, bigdecimal

I am testing with JUnit a PLSQL procedure , to his "equals" in Java/Hibernate.
One result in PLSQL it is 0 but the Java result it is 0.0000, I tried using function called `stripTrailingZeros` but didn't work. I think for practical terms there are the same but not sure  at all.

EDIT I want to remove the zeros who does not have numerical significance for example

2.3400 > 2.34

I can do it with `stripTrailingZeros` but when i Apply that function over return the same thing:

0.0000 > 0.0000

Comment: hmmm convert bigdecimal 0.0000 to bigdecimal 0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing the right thing, but the implementation of the method is wrong. In other words, Java is broken. [There is a bug report about this issue](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6480539) but it doesn't seem to be resolved yet. A *Customer Submitted Workaround* is included in the link. Basically, do an explicit `compareTo` with `new BigDecimal("0")`, which works correctly.

Comment: Seems like this should have been caught long ago. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3):

```
BigDecimal bd1 = new BigDecimal("0.0000");
System.out.println(bd1); // -> 0.0000
BigDecimal bd2 = bd1.setScale(0);
System.out.println(bd2); // -> 0
System.out.println(bd1.equals(bd2)); // -> false
System.out.println(bd1.compareTo(bd2) == 0); // -> true
```